# Backpress from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onbackpressed

I am having a **BaseActivity** which has the following flow, **FragmentA** -> **Fragment** B ->**FinalActivity**. Now I want **backpress** with a back button click from **FinalActivity** to **FragmentA**.

From **BaseActivity** I am calling **FragmentA** like,

```
Fragment selectedFragment = FragmentA .newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, selectedFragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.addToBackStack("Some String");
transaction.commit();
```

From **FragmentA** I am calling **FragmentB** like,

```
Fragment selectedFragment = FragmentB.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, selectedFragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.addToBackStack("Some String");
transaction.commit();
```

From **FragmentB** to **FinalActivity** I am calling like this,

```
startActivityForResult(FinalActivity.newIntent(getActivity()), 1);
```

Now from **FinalActivity** back button I want to show **FragmentA**

Help me how to navigate.

Comment: Can you try to `popBackStack()` after starting activity for example: `if (getFragmentManager() != null)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`  - which should remove your FragmentB and leave FragmentA. So after user returns from `FinalActivity` FragmentA should be presented.

Comment: backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
     //onBackpressed();
     }});
     what to call in this function of FinalActivity

Comment: before doing startActivityForResult(FinalActivity.newIntent(getActivity()), 1); add getActivity().onBackpressed();

Comment: @Himeshgoswami Thankyou , it worked!

Comment: @AanchiDev while @Himeshgoswami answer worked, it might not be the better way of doing this. If you do `onBackPressed()` before the `startActivityForResult()`, there will be a split secont where you might see the **FragmentA** before even seeing the **FinalActivity**, but if this is not important to you, Himesh sugestion works fine.

Comment: @miguelarc as you said, a split occured, but i called onBackPressed() after the startActivityForResult(); and its working smoothly.

Comment: Awesome. If you want to take some info from the **FinalActivity** back to the fragment, you can use my answer. Basically after the RESULT_OK validation, you can get the `dataString` from the `resultIntent`. Notice though, the intent passes only basic objects. If you want to pass a custom object, you will probably need to make it `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this, and since you have a `startActivityForResult()` would be to set a result for the activity and when ending it, passing info to the FragmentB. In your `onBackPressed()` method, you can add this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
String dataString = "Some info you might want to return to the fragment...";
resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse(dataString));
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Then, in your **FragmentB**, you must override the `onActivityResult()` method:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == request_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //here you can pop the FragmentB
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will end the **FinalActivity** -> and pass RESULT_OK to the `onActivityResult()` method (which will be called in **FragmentB**), and then pop the FragmentB, to result in a FragmentA being displayed.

**EDIT:** Note that you will need the requestCode from the `startActivityForResult()` to be the same as the one in the `onActivityResult()`, otherwise the fragment won't know which Activity you are trying to get. You can add a static global value if you want.

**EDIT2:** now that I see, in your code you have something like:

```
transaction.addToBackStack("Some String");
```

this "some string" should actually be the `Fragment.getName()`, so that the backstack has track of which fragments are in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
Fragment selectedFragment = FragmentB.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, selectedFragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.commit();
```

If you want to go back to the **Fragment A** then You not need to add the Line Given below
When relpace fragment form **Fragment A** To **Fragment B** Just remove this Given Line form Your Code

```
transaction.addToBackStack("Some String");
```

and Change the Code of the start activity Like this

```
startActivity(getActivity(),FinalActivity.class);
```